# How to manage url redirection to localhost in a dockered jelastic instance

Tags: flowable

I just installed flowable/all-in-one docker image in JElastic. 
When accessing server.xxx/flowable-modeler a redirection is generated http://localhost:8080/flowable-idm/#/login?redirectOnAuthSuccess=true&redirectUrl=http://server.xxx/flowable-modeler/

The instance is not installed locally so the browser may not find it. How to manage these redirections ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It is a redirect from the application inside, Jelastic has nothing to do with it. https://hub.docker.com/r/flowable/all-in-one 
Include Flowable apps
   Flowable IDM (http://localhost:8080/flowable-idm)
   Flowable Modeler (http://localhost:8080/flowable-modeler)
   Flowable Task (http://localhost:8080/flowable-task)
   Flowable Admin (http://localhost:8080/flowable-admin)

https://forum.flowable.org/t/is-it-advisable-to-run-docker-all-in-one-of-flowable-directly-in-production-just-by-configuring-a-postgres-database/4379

Comment: I agree, but i have to manage this redirection with environment variables and my problem is that the environment variales contains '-' characters that seem not supported by JElastic console (like this one by example : FLOWABLE_COMMON_APP_IDM-URL=http://flowable:8080/flowable-idm). Any workaround or solution for this trivial problem ?

Comment: @MichelWicky Can you please help me to solve my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60925265/6097074

Comment: @Jelastic Can you please help me to solve my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60925265/6097074

Answer (score 1):

Looking from the comments the problem is that you can't set the environment variables because they contain `-`. The Flowable UI Applications use Spring Boot and you can benefit from the [Spring Boot Relaxed Binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding).

In this case the `FLOWABLE_COMMON_APP_IDM_URL` can be written like `FLOWABLE_COMMON_APP_IDMURL` and properly detected by the runtime